# Photo album App swift lang, couple functions with errors

Tags: ios, swift

1. Error message "'String?' is not convertible to 'String'"

   ```
   override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:                                   AnyObject?) {
   **if(segue.identifier as String == "viewLargePhoto")**{
       let controller:ViewPhoto = segue.destinationViewController as     ViewPhoto
   let indexPath: NSIndexPath =             self.collectionView.indexPathForCell(sender as UICollectionViewCell)

   controller.photoAsset = self.photoAsset
   controller.assetCollection = self.assetCollection
   ```
2. Error Message: Could not find member 'AspectFill'

   ```
   let asset: PHAsset = self.photoAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
   PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset,         targetSize: PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: .AspectFill, options:         nil,
       resultHandler: {(result:UIImage!, info:NSDictionary!)in
       cell.setThumbnailImage(result)
   })

           return cell
   ```

Please help and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try omitting the explicit type declaration for `info` on your `resultHandler` function. 
Worked for me.